# iOS9 socket connection killed when app is suspended even though app is registered as VOIP

Tags: ios, sockets, background, ios9, voip

I have an iOS app which uses the VOIP property in iOS to have the socket connection maintained in the background. The app is not actually VOIP but I have used the property so that the socket connection is not killed when app is suspended. This worked just fine in iOS8. But while testing with iOS9, I can see that the socket gets killed a few min after the app is minimized and the device is locked.
If the device is not locked ie. I minimize my app and keep using the device, the socket connection is not killed.
Have anyone faced such an issue. Is there any extra configuration required for VOIP apps in iOS9?
Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Hi Chinta, 
I am Facing same issue. If you resolved this issue can you please share solution with me.

Answer (score 0):

I have an App, where I need to "keep alive" a TCP socket. In My case I use the App with background mode "External Accessory communication". In that case I use Apple Watch to send a request to the iPhone and the iPhone open the TCP connection with a remote device to ask temperature, or light status to a domotic system. Every time the iPhone is able to open the TCP connection and send / receive data from a remote server but after a while the connection is automatically closed. I suggest to try this mode instead VOIP mode.

Comment: Thanks,    but this is not exactly what i wanted. The VOIP app should be able to keep itself alive as per apple "When incoming traffic is detected, the system wakes up the VoIP app and returns control of its sockets to it." There is definitely something going on in the iOS 9 preventing my app to maintain its connection to the server when in background.

Answer (score 0):

As per the new IOS [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp/StrategiesforImplementingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW13), In iOS 8 and later, you can use the Apple Push Notification service (APNs) and the APIs of the PushKit framework to create a VoIP app. Relying on push notifications to enable VoIP functionality means that your app doesn’t have to maintain a persistent network connection to the associated service or configure a socket for VoIP usage. When a VoIP push notification arrives, your app is given time to handle the notification, even if the app is currently terminated.

Comment: But using APNS would only help to invoke my app. In my case the socket connection with the server is created for communicating between user and server. This should remain open as long as the user wishes.I could may be change the design such that each time i receive a notification(if I use APNS), I create a new socket connection to the server. But this is what I am trying to avoid. And I am not sure why Apple would want to change the feature which was working in iOS 8. Even now their documentation clearly says that they would hold on to the connection until a resource constraint occurs.